# How to parallelize sequential tasks using c# and parallel extensions?

Tags: c#, parsing, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions

I have the following method that are called sequentially:

1. private StringBuilder ReadPDF();
2. private StringBuilder CleanText(StringBuilder sb);
3. private void ParseText();

ParseText calls ReadPDF that calls CleanText;

The PDF I'm parsing have 15MB of text and it takes 10 minutes to extract all data from the file using a regular core 2 duo computer.

How can I parallelize these tasks?

edit: Just to clarify, reading the PDF takes very little time, the problem lies with parsing the extracted text, more specifically in the CleanText phase. The reason why I need to parallelize is that cleaning up a single page is instant, but cleaning 2k+ pages takes a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you probably need to review the way you're reading the PDF. If it is only 15MB it cannot take 10 minutes to read unless you're using some VERY-VERY bad way of parsing it.
Second, after you will find the way of parsing it better, you should be sure that you can read a single page at a time from any page you need. After that you will be able to run multiple tasks of reading a single page in parallel.

Comment: Reading the pdf is not taking 10 minutes, it usually takes 10 seconds for each 2k pages because i read them preserving the document structure. What takes 14 minutes is the cleanup of the text.

Comment: @anthony, what does the CleanText do so it takes SO LONG? Once again, I cannot think about any process that should take so long even if it does a "video" processing of the text

Comment: actually it was my mistake. I was going thru the entire text to find one match and repeating the process for every single match I needed. Since the text is really hard to parse (no pattern) thats why it was taking so long. I followed you advice, parallel parsing of single pages took the parsing time from 10+ minutes to 6 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Read the PDF page by page and use Pipelining to process each page.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/14/9995613.aspx

And as was mentioned in a post before, probably you're doing something wrong. It's ONLY 15MB PDF, it shouldn't take 10 minutes to read it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that reading the PDF is fast, the problem is cleaning it up so I can extract the data I need.

Comment: Wow, pipelining is just exactly what I'm after: tasks that use the output of other tasks to produce an end result, right?!

Comment: @anthony: Unless you're doing some seriously black magic analysis, cleaning up 15 megabytes' worth of data should take no time at all for reasonably efficient code.  Without seeing some sample code it's hard to say where the time could be going, but a good place to look is string handling.  Pretty much every string operation creates a completely new string in memory, so it's easy to waste a whole lot of time doing things like successive calls to String.Replace() if you're working with a lot of text.

Comment: I'm using strinbuilders wherever possible so to limit the new strings created. Here is a simplified version of the code I'm using to clean the text: http://pastebin.com/TBFpnMxQ

Comment: The way you're using StringBuilder is probably making the problem worse instead of better.  Every call you make to sb.ToString() will create a completely new copy of all of the text.  One example of a better pattern would be to break the input into smaller units that you can return as IEnuemrable<string>, and then create a set of smaller procedures that use enumerator blocks to successively remove unwanted text (by simply not `yield return`ing it) and transform the rest into a stream of data.

Comment: Actually sb.ToString() returns a reference to the internal string used by sb. The only time sb makes a new string when .ToString() is called is when the internal string is changed (as in user called .Remove or .Append, etc).  What you're saying is to instead of using sb, use blocks of strings?

Comment: It only does that if its internal buffer is currently a single string.  If you've made any edits to the SB, then that probably won't be the case. So it needs to first collect the buffer into a single string before handing back a reference to it.  Doing that requires making a whole new copy of all of the data, which will be very time-consuming for large amounts of text. Instead, when you're dealing with lots of text it's better to break it into smaller chunks.  That way edits can't invalidate anything more than the chunk being edited rather than, say, an entire several-megabyte block of RAM.

Comment: Correction to the previous comment:  I just double-checked how StringBuilder works in Reflector, and at least in .NET 4 it looks like StringBuilder.ToString() **always** allocates a brand-new string.

Answer (score 0):

As Denis said you can read a portion of the text, typically a page, but you might be able to break it into smaller blocks, then process that text while you are reading the next portion of text.

If you want to learn more about parallel programming you can find good info and labs at the [MSDN Parallel Computing center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/bb964701).

MDN also has a [Parallel Programming with .NET blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/).

There is also a good book Professional Parallel Programming with C#: Master Parallel Extensions with .NET 4 by Gastón Hillar